# Equation 6.3 from "deep learning book"

Tags: deep-learning

I have been working through [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) and found that there seems to be a disconnect between equation 6.3 and the steps taken to solve that equation.

Equation 6.3 is

$f(x;W,c,w,b) = w^Tmax\{0,W^Tx+c\}+b$

yet in solving this equation the design matrix $X$ is used instead of $x$, 6.7, and the transpose of $W$ is never applied. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is a column vector and $X$ is a matrix. When you do $W^Tx$ you obtain column vector, so it's correct to write equation in this way. But in the matrix $X$ each row is a data sample. It means that matrix $X$ stores multiple row vectors and they are transposed compare to the $x$ defined in the formula (6.3).

$$
(W^Tx)^T = x^TW
$$

For specific case where you deal with one sample in the matrix $X$ the following equation will be valid

$$
x^TW = XW
$$

If you add more samples to matrix $X$ the final equation $XW$ still will be valid.